# TensorFlow: Are my logits in the right format for cross entropy function?

Tags: tensorflow, cross-entropy

Alright, so I'm getting ready to run the [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) function in Tensorflow.

It's my understanding that the 'logits' should be a Tensor of probabilities, each one corresponding to a certain pixel's probability that it is part of an image that will ultimately be a "dog" or a "truck" or whatever... a finite number of things.

These logits will get plugged into this cross entropy equation:
[image: Cross entropy formula from Wikipedia]

As I understand it, the logits are plugged into the right side of the equation.  That is, they are the q of every x (image).  If they were probabilities from 0 to 1... that would make sense to me.  But when I'm running my code and ending up with a tensor of logits, I'm not getting probabilities. Instead I'm getting floats that are both positive and negative:

```
-0.07264724 -0.15262917  0.06612295 ..., -0.03235611  0.08587133 0.01897052 0.04655019 -0.20552202  0.08725972 ..., -0.02107313 -0.00567073 0.03241089 0.06872301 -0.20756687  0.01094618 ...,   etc
```

So my question is... is that right?  Do I have to somehow calculate all my logits and turn them into probabilities from 0 to 1?

Comment: A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995), which outlines the differences between different cross-entropy functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The crucial thing to note is that [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) performs an internal softmax on each row of `logits` so that they *are* interpretable as probabilities before they are fed to the cross entropy equation.

Therefore, the "`logits`" need not be probabilities (or even true log probabilities, as the name would suggest), because of the internal normalization that happens within that op.

An alternative way to write:

```
xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
```

...would be:

```
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
xent = -tf.reduce_sum(labels * tf.log(softmax), 1)
```

However, this alternative would be (i) less numerically stable (since the softmax may compute much larger values) and (ii) less efficient (since some redundant computation would happen in the backprop). For real uses, we recommend that you use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`.

Comment: Does it mean that I can simply provide `output` as `logits`?

Comment: @mrry what about `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` ? It provides thhe same as `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` but without labels one hot encoding. Is it right ?

Comment: @mrry If I have to predict images and classify them in 3 classes, and every images could belongs only to one category, is it prefereable using the sparse method ?

Comment: @Kyrol Yes, it saves you the work of converting your labels to one-hot vectors. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/tensorflow-whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logi). (Plus, I *think* that the sparse version might also be more efficient than the one-hot version, though I don't have any proof.)