# What's the difference between sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

I recently came across [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) and I can not figure out what the difference is compared to [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).

Is the only difference that training vectors `y` have to be [one-hot encoded](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/321/lec/W04/onehot.pdf) when using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Reading the API, I was unable to find any other difference compared to `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. But why do we need the extra function then?

Shouldn't `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` produce the same results as `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, if it is supplied with one-hot encoded training data/vectors?

Comment: I'm interested in seeing a comparison of their performance if both can be used (e.g. with exclusive image labels); I'd expect the sparse version to be more efficient, at least memory-wise.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995), which discusses *all cross-entropy functions* in tensorflow (turns out there are lots of them).

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Having two different functions is a **convenience**, as they produce the same result.

The difference is simple:

- For `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, labels must have the shape [batch_size] and the dtype int32 or int64. Each label is an int in range `[0, num_classes-1]`.
- For `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, labels must have the shape [batch_size, num_classes] and dtype float32 or float64.

Labels used in `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` are the **one hot version** of labels used in `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Another tiny difference is that with `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, you can give -1 as a label to have loss `0` on this label.

Comment: Is the -1 correct? As the documentation reads: "Each entry in labels must be an index in [0, num_classes). Other values will raise an exception when this op is run on CPU, and return NaN for corresponding loss and gradient rows on GPU."

Comment: [0, num_classes) = [0, num_classes-1]

Comment: Is this statement correct? "Labels used in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits are the one hot version of labels used in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits." Is it backwards? Isn't the sparse loss function the one with int of 0, so isn't the sparse one the one-hot version?

Answer (score 28):

I would just like to add 2 things to accepted answer that you can also find in TF documentation.

First:

> tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
>
> NOTE: While the classes are mutually exclusive, their probabilities
> need not be. All that is required is that each row of labels is a
> valid probability distribution. If they are not, the computation of
> the gradient will be incorrect.

Second:

> tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
>
> NOTE: For this operation, the probability of a given label is
> considered exclusive. That is, soft classes are not allowed, and the
> labels vector must provide a single specific index for the true class
> for each row of logits (each minibatch entry).

Comment: What should we use if the classes are not mutually exclusive. I mean if we're combining multiple categorical labels?

Comment: I also read this. So it means we apply the class probability on the cross entropy rather than taking it as a onehot vector.

Comment: @Hayro - Do you mean you are unable to do one hot encoding? I think you would have to look at a different model. [This](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression) mentioned something like " it would be more appropriate to build 4 binary logistic regression classifiers" To first make sure you can separate the classes.

Answer (score 22):

Both functions computes the same results and [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) computes the cross entropy directly on the sparse labels instead of converting them with [one-hot encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33681732/1090562).

You can verify this by running the following program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from random import randint

dims = 8
pos  = randint(0, dims - 1)

logits = tf.random_uniform([dims], maxval=3, dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.one_hot(pos, dims)

res1 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(       logits=logits, labels=labels)
res2 = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf.constant(pos))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b = sess.run([res1, res2])
    print a, b
    print a == b
```

Here I create a random `logits` vector of length `dims` and generate one-hot encoded labels (where element in `pos` is 1 and others are 0).

After that I calculate softmax and sparse softmax and compare their output. Try rerunning it a few times to make sure that it always produce the same output