# LSTM model error is percent of one output class

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I'm having a rough time trying to figure out what's wrong with my LSTM model. I have 11 inputs, and 2 output classes (one-hot encoded) and very quickly, like within 1 batch or so, the error just goes to the % of one of the output classes and stays there.

I tried printing weights and biases, but they seem to all be full of NaN.

If i decrease the learning rate, or mess around with layers/units, I can get it to arrive at the % of one class error slowly, but it seems to always get to that point.

Here's the code:

```
num_units = 30
num_layers = 50
dropout_rate = 0.80
learning_rate=0.0001
batch_size = 180
epoch = 1

input_classes = len(train_input[0])
output_classes = len(train_output[0])

data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_classes, 1]) #Number of examples, number of input, dimension of each input
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_classes]) #one-hot encoded: [1,0] = bad, [0,1] = good
dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units, state_is_tuple=True)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=dropout)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

#Input shape [batch_size, max_time, depth], output shape: [batch_size, max_time, cell.output_size]
val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32) 

val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2]) #reshapes it to [sequence_size, batch_size, depth]

#get last entry as it includes previous results
last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

weight = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[num_units, output_classes], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
bias   = tf.get_variable("B", shape=[output_classes], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
logits = tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias

prediction = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=target)
prediction = tf.clip_by_value(prediction, 1e-10,100.0)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(prediction)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cost)

mistakes = tf.not_equal(tf.argmax(target, 1), tf.argmax(logits, 1))
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

no_of_batches = int((len(train_input)) / batch_size)
for i in range(epoch):
    ptr = 0
    for j in range(no_of_batches):
        inp, out = train_input[ptr:ptr+batch_size], train_output[ptr:ptr+batch_size]
        ptr+=batch_size
        sess.run(minimize,{data: inp, target: out, dropout: dropout_rate })

sess.close()
```

Comment: Is there any out of memory notifications  ?

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Nope, no errors. I've tried it on multiple machines too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have one hot encoding use ***sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits*** instead of *tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits*.

Refer to this stackoverflow answer to understand the difference of two functions.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/tensorflow-whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logi)

Comment: Ah, I actually read that post but got it backwards. That being said I've tried different cost functions too, previously the code was: prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias) and then prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias). But same thing happens.

Comment: So you accuracy doesn't change? It's stuck to one value is it ?

Comment: If the mini-batch size is very low, like 5, then it usually takes about 1-3 mini-batches to settle on a value. Any batch size higher it will immediately settle on an error rate of 1 classes percentage. Obviously this all depends on the other parameters, most of the time it's immediate. Also, I converted my labels to a sparse tensor and used sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, but I get the same results. For example, my test data has about 32% of class [0,1], and the accuracy became that immediately and won't change.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it .What do you mean by "settle on a value", And "error rate of 1 classes percentage".

Comment: It's working now, I think the sparse change and patience did it. Thanks.