# When I am trying to execute my RNN code in TensorFlow, it is showing the following errors?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.5, recurrent-neural-network

[The tensorflow code is attached, please assist](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4m2UBA0JadVWUdsV2dET3JhZ0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Don't share files here. please add code.

Answer (score 0):

**List of errors**

*Error 1:*

> TypeError: Input 'split_dim' of 'Split' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of int32.

From: `x = tf.split(0, n_chunks, x)`
To: `x = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=n_chunks, value=x)`

*Error 2:*

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.rnn_cell' has no attribute 'BasicLSTMCell'

From:
`from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import rnn_cell`
`lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True)`
To:
`from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import BasicLSTMCell`
`lstm_cell = BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True)`

*Error 3:*

> NameError: name 'rnn' is not defined

From: `outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)`
To: `outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=x, dtype=tf.float32)`

*Error 4:*

> ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 3 for 'transpose_3' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,28], [3].

Comment:
 
`x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
 x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
 x = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=n_chunks, value=x)`

*Error 5:*

> ValueError: Only call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

From:
 `cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )`
To:
 `cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))`

*Error 6:*

> InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[28,10] labels_size=[128,10]

That's a *maybe concept* problem with the `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` function. Take a look at: [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/tensorflow-whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logi) and [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

Start understanding and fixing all these problems. If you still aren't able to run the code, come back and post the updated code, but, at least, with that 6 problems solved :)