# Loss is equal to 0 from the beginning

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm trying to attempt the Titanic Kaggle competition using Tensorflow.

My pre processed train data looks like this:

```
data_x:

PassengerId  Pclass  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch  Ticket Fare  Cabin  \ Embarked
1              2       1    1  38.0      1      0     500   71.2833    104
2              3       3    1  26.0      0      0     334    7.9250      0
3              4       1    1  35.0      1      0     650   53.1000    130
4              5       3    0  35.0      0      0     638    8.0500      0

data_y:

Survived
0
1
1
1
0
```

A softmax function should do the work to predict if a passenger survived or not since it's binary, right?

So here is how I build my model:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, data_x.shape[1]])
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001

#The model
Y = tf.matmul(X,W) + b

# Loss function
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_, logits=Y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy) # computes the mean over examples in the batch

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

acc = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(acc, tf.float32))

tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', acc)
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

And finallyn, the training part:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./graphs", sess.graph)
    for i in range(1000):
        _, l, summary = sess.run([optimizer, loss, merged_summary], feed_dict={X: data_x, Y_: data_y})
        writer.add_summary(summary, i)
        if i%100 == 0:
            print (i)
            print ("loss = ", l)
```

But loss is equals to 0 since the first step...

Here is Tensorboard visualization:

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think you got the idea of softmax wrong.
It transformes outputs such that they are a probability distribution.
However, as your output is only one neuron, softmax always transforms it to 1.

If you want softmax + cross entropy with logits, you need to ouput 2 neurons, one for probability of prediction being 1 (positive), one for probability of it being 0 (negative). Also you need to change labels, such that positive example has label `[1, 0]`, negative `[0, 1]`. Then, you can use cross entropy and it should work.

EDIT: Another good option might be to use 
`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` loss function. Sigmoid does the transformation to the `[0, 1]` interval you need for cross-entropy, and doesn't worry about (possible) other outputs. This way, it would work with your current labels and architecture.

Comment: Of course! I forgot... It must be one hot encoded. I'll give it a try and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_, logits=Y)
```

instead

```
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_, logits=Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain the diffrerence between those two?

Comment: You can found explanation in answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/tensorflow-whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logi