# My classifier has very big loss and accuracy is always 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss

I'm training a **classifier** to get a **factor** for an optimization. 
My data-set contains 800 samples as beginning (some are similar with just few modification).

I developed my model with TensorFlow using GoogleColab environment.

I have used a simple **MLP** for this problem, with **3 hidden layers** each one has 256 nodes as first stage. I have also **64 classes** .

I have **variable length** inputs and I had fixed this problem with **"-1" padding**.

with my actual features I know that I will get bad accuracy, but I did not expect **zero accuracy** and the **very big loss**.

This was my data-set after omitting some features that I have noticed that influence negatively the accuracy :

```
     0  1   2   4  5  6  8  9   11  13    15      17    19      21
805  6  10  11  1  3  1  6  64  2   1.0   64.0    64.0  64.0    -1.0
334  6  12  18  0  2  4  7  2   1   32.0  128.0   64.0  128.0   -1.0
781  7  10  11  1  3  1  6  2   2   2.0   64.0    32.0  32.0    64.0
```

[Edited] : And here is some lines of my labels:

```
    0
0   108
1   30
2   30
3   16
4   62
5   126
6   22
7   30
8   48
```

And here is a set of my result :

```
epoch[0] step [0] train -- loss : 50751.734375, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[0] step [100] train -- loss : 27310.064453125, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[0] step [200] train -- loss : 58120.6015625, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[0] step [300] train -- loss : 31801.9453125, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[0] step [400] train -- loss : 54360.76171875, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[0] step [500] train -- loss : 59946.67578125, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[1] step [0] train -- loss : 40612.06640625, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[1] step [100] train -- loss : 43229.734375, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[1] step [200] train -- loss : 36951.84375, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[1] step [300] train -- loss : 45225.828125, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[1] step [400] train -- loss : 47055.1796875, accuracy : 0.0
epoch[1] step [500] train -- loss : 54023.23046875, accuracy : 0.0
```

I wonder why I get this big loss, and also that my loss **does not converge** too :(.

Those was the bizarre graph of accuracy and loss I got :

[image: those was the bizarre graph of accuracy and loss I got :(]

My code work perfectly, but I still doubt maybe my I did not write things well so I got this mess.

This is the important part of my code :

```
class MLP():
    '''
      This is the implementation of the Multi Layer Perceptron
    '''
    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train, n_classes, n_hiddens=3, activation=tf.nn.relu):
      ...       
    ################################ Create the model ##############################    
    def multilayer_perceptron(self,X):      
        # Hidden fully connected layer with n_hidden_1 neurons
        layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=X, units= self.n_hidden_1, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self._init, name= 'layer_1')
        layer_1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_1,training=self.is_train)
        layer_1 = self.activation(layer_1)     

        # Hidden fully connected layer with n_hidden_2 neurons
        layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units= self.n_hidden_2, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self._init, name= 'layer_2')
        layer_2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_2,training=self.is_train)
        layer_2 = self.activation(layer_2)   

        # Hidden fully connected layer with n_hidden_3 neurons
        layer_3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_2, units= self.n_hidden_3, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self._init, name= 'layer_3')
        layer_3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_3, training=self.is_train)
        layer_3 = self.activation(layer_3)  

        # Output fully connected layer with the output
        out_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_3, units= self.n_classes, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self._init, name= 'out_layer')

        tf.summary.histogram('pre-activations', out_layer) 
        return layer_1, layer_2, layer_3, out_layer
```

And here where I calculate the loss and accuracy of training set :

```
 def loss(self, X, Y):
        _, _, _, self.predicted_out = self.multilayer_perceptron(X) 
        print("Predicted out", self.predicted_out)
        with tf.name_scope('loss'):          
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=self.predicted_out, labels=Y))
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss) 

        with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
                predicted_class = tf.nn.softmax(self.predicted_out)
                with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
                    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predicted_class, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
                with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
                    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))
        tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
        self.merged =  tf.summary.merge_all()

        return loss, accuracy
```

This the function of training :

```
def train(self):
        self.train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./Graph', self.sess.graph) 
    # training data
        train_input = self.Normalize(self.x_train)
        train_output = self.y_train.copy()

        save_sess=self.sess

      #costs history :
        costs = []
        costs_inter=[] 
      #for early stopping :
        best_cost=1000000
        stop = False
        last_improvement=0

        n_samples = train_input.shape[0] # size of the training set

       #train the mini_batches model using the early stopping criteria
        epoch = 0
        while epoch < self.max_epochs and stop == False:
            #train the model on the traning set by mini batches
            #suffle then split the training set to mini-batches of size self.batch_size
            seq =list(range(n_samples))
            random.shuffle(seq)
            mini_batches = [
                seq[k:k+self.batch_size]
                for k in range(0,n_samples, self.batch_size)
            ]

            avg_cost = 0. # The average cost of mini_batches
            step= 0

            for sample in mini_batches:                  
                batch_x = x_train.iloc[sample, :]
                batch_y =train_output.iloc[sample, :]
                feed_dict={self.X: batch_x,self.Y:batch_y, self.is_train:True}
                self.train_summary, _, cost,acc=self.sess.run([self.merged, self.train_step, self.loss_, self.accuracy_], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                avg_cost += cost *len(sample)/n_samples      
                print('epoch[{}] step [{}] train -- loss : {}, accuracy : {}'.format(epoch,step, cost, acc))
                self.train_writer.add_summary(self.train_summary, global_step=step)
                step += 100

            #cost history since the last best cost
            costs_inter.append(avg_cost)
            epoch +=1

        #Test the model 
        pred = tf.nn.softmax(self.predicted_out)  # Apply softmax to logits
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(self.Y, 1))
        # Calculate accuracy
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        accuracy_test = self.sess.run([accuracy],feed_dict={self.X: x_test, self.Y: y_test,self.is_train:False})
        #print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({self.X: x_test, self.Y: y_test}))
        print("Accuracy_test : ", accuracy_test)

        # Writes the summaries to disk
        self.train_writer.flush()
        # Flushes the summaries to disk and closes the SummaryWriter
        self.train_writer.close()                              
        return costs
```

Here where I call my method train, I was planing to apply cross validation to see if I can improve the model accuracy but I had not yet :

```
def cross_validation(self,batch_size, n_hidden_1 , n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3, learning_rate):
        ##### Other parameter 
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_hidden_1 = n_hidden_1
        self.n_hidden_2 = n_hidden_2
        self.n_hidden_3 = n_hidden_3
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.require_improvement= 20
        self.max_epochs = 80
        self._init = tf.random_normal_initializer
        self.optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer      
        loss = 0   
        tf.reset_default_graph()

        with tf.name_scope('input'):
          self.X=tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None,self.x_train.shape[1]])
          self.Y=tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None,self.y_train.shape[1]])
          self.is_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name="is_train") 
        self.loss_, self.accuracy_ = self.loss(self.X, self.Y)
        self.train_step = self.optimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss_)

        # Initiate a tensor session
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(init)

        #train the model 
        loss = self.train()

        self.sess.close()
        del self.sess
        return  loss
```

And finally this my main:

```
  if __name__=='__main__':
  tbc = tb.TensorBoardColab()
  mlp =   MLP(x_train, y_train, n_classes)
  loss= mlp.cross_validation(batch_size, n_hidden_1 , n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3, learning_rate)
```

I had expected to get bad accuracy but not "0" and the very big loss without any convergence has shocked me. Can someone tell me where are the problems here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are quite a few points you need to take care of

1. you should remove the tf summary file before the start of each training, as the global step will restart from 0 according to your code
2. your loss function is `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`, to use this you may need to encode your label in onehot, and try to minimize logit layer close to that onehot label with internal softmax function in this function. If you want to keep current ground truth label, please check [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). The usages are similar but some of them need to be onehot label. Check detailed explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-and-softm)

Comment: if I remove the summary before each training then when should I keep it ?

Comment: I change my Y placeholder to `self.Y=tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None])` but I got this error : `Cannot feed value of shape (100, 1) for Tensor 'input/Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?,)'` I tried many ways to fix it but I failed.