# Calculating Cross Entropy in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, cross-entropy

I am having a hard time with calculating cross entropy in tensorflow. In particular, I am using the function:

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()
```

Using what is seemingly simple code, I can only get it to return a zero

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape =[None, 1])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 1])
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
c = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=b, labels=a
).eval(feed_dict={b:np.array([[0.45]]), a:np.array([[0.2]])})
print c
```

returns

```
0
```

My understanding of cross entropy is as follows:

```
H(p,q) = p(x)*log(q(x))
```

Where p(x) is the true probability of event x and q(x) is the predicted probability of event x.

There if input any two numbers for p(x) and q(x) are used such that

```
0<p(x)<1 AND 0<q(x)<1
```

there should be a nonzero cross entropy. I am expecting that I am using tensorflow incorrectly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So, interestingly I got the idea of using cross entropy from this project:

https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py

they are using it to identify whether or not a sample comes from a real distribution. However, it seems that a binary softmax regression is the same as a logistic regression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like they say, you can't spell "softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits" without "softmax". Softmax of `[0.45]` is `[1]`, and `log(1)` is `0`.

> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which the
>   classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one class).  For
>   example, each CIFAR-10 image is labeled with one and only one label: an image
>   can be a dog or a truck, but not both.
>
> **NOTE:**  While the classes are mutually exclusive, their probabilities
>   need not be.  All that is required is that each row of `labels` is
>   a valid probability distribution.  If they are not, the computation of the
>   gradient will be incorrect.
>
> If using exclusive `labels` (wherein one and only
>   one class is true at a time), see `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.
>
> **WARNING:** This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a `softmax`
>   on `logits` internally for efficiency.  Do not call this op with the
>   output of `softmax`, as it will produce incorrect results.
>
> `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`
>   and the same dtype (either `float16`, `float32`, or `float64`).

Comment: Aha! So it seems my problems are caused by a misunderstanding of softmax! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DavidKaftan, if this solves your problem, it would be nice to mark this as accepted answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm (obviously) new here!

Answer (score 20):

In addition to Don's answer (+1), [this answer written by mrry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086477/395857) may interest you, as it gives the formula to calculate the cross entropy in TensorFlow:

> An alternative way to write:
>
> ```
> xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
> ```
>
> ...would be:
>
> ```
> softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
> xent = -tf.reduce_sum(labels * tf.log(softmax), 1)
> ```
>
> However, this alternative would be (i) less numerically stable (since
>   the softmax may compute much larger values) and (ii) less efficient
>   (since some redundant computation would happen in the backprop). For
>   real uses, we recommend that you use
>   `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`.

Comment: Thank you for the (no-softmax) cross-entropy formula

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation in Tensorflow 2.0 in case somebody else (me probably) needs it in the future.

```py
@tf.function
def cross_entropy(x, y, epsilon = 1e-9):
    return -2 * tf.reduce_mean(y * tf.math.log(x + epsilon), -1) / tf.math.log(2.)

x = tf.constant([
    [1.0,0],
    [0.5,0.5],
    [.75,.25]
    ]
,dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(x)
    y = entropy(x, x)

tf.print(y)
tf.print(tape.gradient(y, x))
```

Output

```
[-0 1 0.811278105]
[[-1.44269502 29.8973541]
 [-0.442695022 -0.442695022]
 [-1.02765751 0.557305]]
```