# Tensorflow possible update to high level estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generator

I have trained a Deep Neural Network Regressor on some weather data. When I tried classifier.predict(), it return a generator object. Usually what we do is to put list() over the object to get the prediction.

It used to work but I believe that after a recent update, it is no longer working. I'm currently on tensorflow 1.7.0. I tried downgrading to several version of tensorflow and could not locate one that worked.

```
import tensorflow as tf
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[163])]
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[200,100,20],
                                        model_dir='model/'
                                        )
onehot,price=load_single_data([[5,18,16,1],'Mostly Sunny','Mostly Sunny',46.5])

prediction= classifier.predict(np.array(onehot))
#This line produced the error
print(list(prediction))
```

The error produced is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\inspect.py", line 1089, in getfullargspec
    sigcls=Signature)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\inspect.py", line 2156, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]) is not a callable object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/5V/PycharmProjects/UberAPI/deep_learning.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(list(prediction))
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 486, in predict
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 662, in _get_features_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 763, in _call_input_fn
    input_fn_args = util.fn_args(input_fn)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\util.py", line 55, in fn_args
    args = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(fn).args
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_inspect.py", line 67, in getfullargspec
    if d.decorator_argspec is not None), spec_fn(target))
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\inspect.py", line 1095, in getfullargspec
    raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Doing this will produce:

```
print(prediction)
>> <generator object Estimator.predict at 0x00000069E3AC0BF8>
```

---

Alright, here is a complete traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\inspect.py", line 1089, in getfullargspec
    sigcls=Signature)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\inspect.py", line 2156, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]) is not a callable object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/5V/PycharmProjects/UberAPI/deep_learning.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(list(prediction))
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 486, in predict
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 662, in _get_features_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 763, in _call_input_fn
    input_fn_args = util.fn_args(input_fn)
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\util.py", line 55, in fn_args
    args = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(fn).args
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_inspect.py", line 67, in getfullargspec
    if d.decorator_argspec is not None), spec_fn(target))
  File "C:\Users\5V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\inspect.py", line 1095, in getfullargspec
    raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Comment: It seems to me the problem is that `np.array(onehot)` is not a proper `input_fn`. Are you sure this worked for you before? Could you please provide a complete Traceback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported callable using Dataset with estimator input\_fn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120637/typeerror-unsupported-callable-using-dataset-with-estimator-input-fn)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have other bugs here. Based on the traceback, it is clear that this specific error is resulted from using `np.array(onehot)` as `input_fn` for `classifier.predict`, i.e. numpy array is not a callable object. To fix this, you can use [`numpy_input_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn):

```
input_predict= tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': np.array(onehot)}, shuffle=False)
print(list(model.predict(input_predict)))
```

## Edit: about shape mismatch

Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show one potential cause of

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with ...

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
        hidden_units=[20, 20],
        feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='x')],
        model_dir=r"E:\GitHub\miscellaneous\ml-models\foobar\tensorflow\test"
    )

input_train= tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={'x': np.arange(100)},
        y=np.arange(100),
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True
    )
model.train(input_fn=input_train, steps=200)

test = np.array([[200]]) # correct input with shape 1 for each input (row)
#test = np.array([[200, 300]]) # incorrect input with shape 2 for each input (row)
input_predict= tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        {'x': test}, shuffle=False
    )
print(list(model.predict(input_predict)))
```

As commented in the code, correct inputs should have only one feature rather than two.

Comment: Trying the following produced:

    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape 
    is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 20864

I cannot post full traceback as replies are limited to 500 chars.

Comment: @5Volts This is related to your model. I don't know the details but it means your model requires a tensor with shape 20864 as input while your `onehot` (the predict input) has a shape of 128. I guess this is the point where a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is helpful.