# TypeError: unsupported callable on next(<class 'generator'>)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, generator

In the following code:

```
self.estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor( ... )
...
predictions = self.estimator.predict(predict_features)
print("predictions: {}".format(type(predictions)))
while True:
  try:
    result = next(predictions)
    predict_labels.append(result)
  except StopIteration:
    return predict_labels
```

The 2nd line reported that predictions is a `class 'generator'`. However, the line `result = next(predictions)` produced this exception on the 0st iteration:

```
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

Could you tell what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: 1) You are using `while True` to call `next(something)` and you check for `StopIteration`... Are you aware that you are reimplementing the `for` loop? Just do `for result in predictions: predict_labels.append(result)` or even `predict_labels.extend(predictions)` 2) What is `predictions`? It appears to not be a supported callable. That's all we can tell without knowing what `self.estimator.predict(..)` is.

Comment: Is this related to tensorflow? If so, add the tag

Comment: @Bakuriu, 2) predictions is the output of TensorFlow estimator.DNNRegressor

Comment: I'm pretty sure your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120637/typeerror-unsupported-callable-using-dataset-with-estimator-input-fn), however, given that you did not provide enough information, it's impossible to check if that is the case. We need to know exactly how you create the `DNNRegressor`. The error you get happens when you pass a non-function object in place one of the arguments to `DNNRegressor` (or classifier).

Comment: @Bakuriu, this is not the same, `train` worked as expected. Subsequent `predict` also seemed to work; what I don't get is why `next(prediction)` fails despite `prediction` type being class 'generator', which supports the `next` operation.

Comment: @Michael That's easy to explain. `generator`s are *lazy*, so up until you call `next` nothing happens. So only when the first call to `next` happens the code is starting to get evaluated and it realizes that the arguments you passed in wrong.  However without the full code and the full traceback we cannot really say why specifically