# Why can't the output of the network go through a softmax when using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to use the tensorflow built-in cross-entropy function. However, in the documentation, I'm reading

> Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce
>   incorrect results.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Like it is done often, I am using the softmax activation in my last output layer, however:

```
result = tf.layers.dense(input=dropout, classes_num, tf.nn.softmax)
```

Is it, therefore, incorrect to use this function, or is the documentation incorrect? I don't understand this, I would be thankful for a short explanation. 
(Which TensorFlow cost function would be correct to use for a softmax output layer then?)

Comment: See also this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` computes internally the softmax (in a numerically stable way) of its input, you have to define your network in order to use the linear activation function: `tf.identity`

```
result = tf.layers.dense(input=dropout, classes_num, tf.identity)
```

Moreover, once the network has been trained and you want to use use the model for inference, you have to replace the activation with the softmax.

Thus, introduce in your code a `is_training` python boolean variable, and use it to change your model definition when you're training or testing.

```
result = tf.layers.dense(input=dropout, classes_num,
             tf.identity if is_training else tf.nn.softmax)
```

Comment: I see. In your implementation, it would be correct to still use `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`, which essentially is `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as the cost function during training, correct?

Answer (score 4):

The function that you have mentioned is **tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits**. As the name suggests, it first performs a softmax (*i.e* scaling) on logits and then calculates the entropy between logits and labels.

Therefore, if you input logits (as **result** in your code) that already performed the softmax then you perform the softmax twice on your logits, which will produce incorrect results.

Hope this helps.