# Significance of binary_crossentropy loss when used on for multiclass classification?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, classification

Should you **always** use `categorical_crossentropy` loss for multiclass classification problems? Or does `binary_crossentropy` have significance in some way too?

To be clear, multiclass means an input can take on one of many classes. And the problem is single label, meaning an input cannot take on multiple classes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`K.binary_crossentropy` doesn't make sense for *multi-class* classification, it's for binary *multi-label* classification. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995) outlines the differences in detail. Keep in mind that under the hood<sup>*</sup>:

- `K.binary_crossentropy` is [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)
- `K.categorical_crossentropy` is [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

<sub>* assuming you're using tensorflow backend</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the last layer for binary_crossentropy should always use sigmoid activation and for categorical_crossentropy should always use softmax activation?

also - since binary_crossentropy is multi-label, does that mean the probabilities that are output after the last layer don't have to sum up to 1?

Comment: `binary_crossentropy` itself performs sigmoid activation, that's why tensorflow function is named *with logits*. Additional sigmoid layer will only do harm. The same is true for `categorical_crossentropy`. And yes, the probabilities are per-feature and don't have to sum to 1.

Comment: you sure? almost all examples I've seen with categorical_crossentropy loss have a softmax as the last layer as well.

Comment: Oops, my bad. In Keras, the default is `from_logits=False`, in this case it's expecting an input as probability. But just to make it clear: this way you compute sigmoid output, then convert it back to logits, then apply `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`, which computes sigmoid one more time. Check out the source code. I mostly do it directly in tensorflow and so I never use sigmoid/softmax layer myself.