# TensorFlow sequence_loss with label_smoothing

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy, sequence-to-sequence

Would it be possible to use the `label_smoothing` feature from `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` with `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` ?

I can see that `sequence_loss` optionally takes a `softmax_loss_function` as parameter. However, this function would take the `targets` as a list of ints, instead of one-hot encoded vectors required by `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`, which is also the only function to support `label_smoothing` in TensorFlow.

Can you recommend a way of making label_smoothing work with `sequence_loss` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done efficiently.

[`tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss) is designed to work with very large vocabularies, hence it's expecting a loss function from *sparse* family (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995) for details). The main difference is that labels use *ordinal* encoding instead of *one-hot*, because the latter takes too much memory. Actual one-hot encoding is **never computed**.

`label_smoothing` parameter of [`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy) on the other hand is an option to manipulate the one-hot encoding. Here's what it does:

```py
if label_smoothing > 0:
  num_classes = math_ops.cast(
      array_ops.shape(onehot_labels)[1], logits.dtype)
  smooth_positives = 1.0 - label_smoothing
  smooth_negatives = label_smoothing / num_classes
  onehot_labels = onehot_labels * smooth_positives + smooth_negatives
```

As you can see, to compute this tensor, `onehot_labels` must be stored explicitly, which is exactly what sparse functions try to avoid. That's why neither `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, nor `tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss` provide a similar parameter. Of course, you can do the conversion yourself, but this defeats the whole optimization.